# QtMobility-no service found for - "com.nokia.qt.mediaplayer

Tags: qt-mobility

I have installed QtMobility successfully but when I run my programs, the UI comes up but the media (audio & video) does not play.
This is the error I get through command prompt as well as QtCreator:

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "com.nokia.qt.mediaplayer"

I got the same error when using QtSDK 4.8.1 & 4.7.2

My platform is Ubuntu 10.04 and gstreamer 0.10.6 is also installed on my platform

I had posted the issue in several forums but got no response.
Kindly suggest a solution and help resolve issues.

These are the files in my QtSDK->plugin->mediaservice folder:

- `libqtmedia_audioengine.so`
- `libqtmedia_v4lengine.so`

Is the error related to any `.so` files here?